# Kafka reproduced deleted topics when produce new topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I use KafkaAdminClient to delete Kafka topics in my Java project. I delete my topics then I produce a message to a new topic. Kafka creates my old topics again. [kafka server.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmewo.png)

I have `"allow.auto.create.topics" : "false"` configuration on consumer instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must send `auto.create.topics.enable=false` in the configuration of the broker. It also depends on how your producer is implemented. In case of Kafka Streams this property is not applied.

Comment: How can I configure auto.create.topics configuration in Spring Kafka. I added "spring.kafka.consumer.properties.auto.create.topics.enable=false
spring.kafka.producer.properties.auto.create.topics.enable=false" in application.properties file, but not working

Comment: It must be done in the kafka server configuration, not on the client

Comment: I use this code to send a message on the topic.  "kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);" This code create a topic and send a message.  If I do the configuration, I have to create the topic myself, right? 
Should I use kafkaAdmin or Spring Boot's kafkaTemplate when creating topics?

Comment: Yes, if you disable auto creation, you should create the topic yourself. You can do it with a command line tool, or through API with a Kafka Admin client

Comment: Should I build my Producer and Consumer with Spring Framework Kafka? 
Why do we create the topic with Kafka Admin instead of producer?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue and this is how I solved it in my situation:

1. You no longer have any active subscriptions to that topic, thus you should unsubscribe before deleting.
2. You have to close the producer that produced messages into that topic.

Apparently, if you don't do all that, Kafka kinda holds some connection to the topic and doesn't let it get removed.